# Config service from directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Im trying to create simple plugin in AngularJs, customizable from directive attributes

 e.g. `<div my-dir attr-first="obj={ .... }"></div>`
obj should configure my "setting service" before compiling, just like provider, because css depends on it.

Is there a way to get attributes from provider? 
Or somehow configure service from directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes are passed into both the `compile` and `link` functions for your [Directive](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/guide/directive):

```
function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) { ... }
//                         ^^^^^^

function link(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) { ... }
//                             ^^^^^^
```

Deep linking for the Angular documentation seems to be broken... Visit http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/guide and then select "Directives"